# Execute code after CompleteRequest()

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, threadabortexception

I have to execute some more code after downloading a file, but itsn't happening. The compiler hits `ClearControls();` after `DownloadFile();`, but the function is not executed.
On the page I get the prompt to open or save the file. But the textboxes are not cleared.
What should be done in this case.

```
protected void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//ClearControls(); // not working here too.
DownloadFile();
ClearControls();
}

private void DownloadFile()
{
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="+sName+".pdf");
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/documents/ready/" + strPdfName));
//Response.End();
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
}

private void ClearControls()
{
  txtOne.Text="";
  txtTwo.Text="";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your download is basically overriding the writing to the browser, you're getting one response back and it's the file with all the header information.

You're kinda stuck if you really need to update the form at this point. Best bet would be to open the download in a new tab or window using javascript or ajax passing in the values you need via the querystring.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the reasons why web pages usually send you to a different page for the download, rather than simply starting the download right away. You need two separate HTTP requests to give two HTTP responses - and since your response already is the file to be downloaded, there's no way to send a response that should be included as part of the original page.

Comment: Right. Here is my case - User fills in a form and then gets the download option. The fileid comes from queryString. If I redirect to another page, then users can directly try 'download.aspx?id=1...' to download files even without registering. So, any other option here...

Comment: @Qwerty: Well, you can use pretty much any authentication method you want, set a cookie, use a unique, one-use download link... There's quite a few options.